# R- store data as data.frame in a loop

Tags: r

Is there a better way to store the data generated in the loop as data.frame (but still using a loop)?

script:

```
resX<-c()
resY<-c()
Mystep <- 2 

for(i in seq(0, 10, by = Mystep  )){
  resX[i]  <-i*10
  resY[i]  <-i/10     
}

Results<-as.data.frame(cbind(resX,resY))
```

Comment: idiomatic R would use vectorised operations. But you could use a for loop if you prespecified the lengths of resX and resY (the dynamic extension of these two vectors in the forloop causes some inefficiencies), eg, resX <- numeric(6).

Comment: The vectorised solution looks like: s <- seq(0, 10, by = Mystep); results <- data.frame(resX = s * 10, resY = s / 10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use a loop, guess this one works

```
Results <- data.frame()
Mystep <- 2 

for(i in seq(0, 10, by = Mystep  )){
  xy = c(i*10, i/10)

  Results = rbind(Results, xy)    
}

names(Results) = c("X", "Y")
> Results
    X  Y
1   0  0.0
2  20  0.2
3  40  0.4
4  60  0.6
5  80  0.8
6 100  1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a loop is not using R efficiently. The vectorized solution is the right answer. But since that is off the table, I don't think a double-loop solution is out of line:

```
data.frame(
  sapply(seq(0, 10, by = Mystep), `*`, 10)),
  sapply(seq(0, 10, by = Mystep), `/`, 10))
)
```

Or (cleaner)

```
itr <- seq(0, 10, by = Mystep)
data.frame(sapply(itr, `*`, 10)), sapply(itr, `/`, 10)))
```

And lastly with a for loop:

```
output <- data.frame(numeric(length(itr)), numeric(length(itr)))
for(i in itr) {
  output[i, 1] <- itr*10
  output[i, 2] <- itr/10
}
```

Comment: I know but in this instance I need a loop.

Comment: What is a "loop" here? `sapply` is a loop, and beats `for` in most cases. Do you mean classical loop structures, `do/while`, `for`, or `repeat`?

Comment: Yes, The classical for loop.